# problem with inserting bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to use achemso package for my bibliography and having problem with my references. But I am unable to see any in pdf generated. This is the package I used

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}% and this is my bib file
@article{1,
  title={Resistance of Neisseria gonorrhoeae to antimicrobial hydrophobic agents is modulated by the mtrRCDE efflux system},
  author={Hagman, Kayla E and Pan, Wubin and Spratt, Brian G and Balthazar, Jacqueline T and Judd, Ralph C and Shafer, William M},
  journal={Microbiology},
  volume={141},
  number={3},
  pages={611--622},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Microbiology Society}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[journal=jacsat, layout=singlecolumn]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle=true}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{natmove}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\title{title}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Could someone please suggest what could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome! If it is really there, start by deleting `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}` from your `.bib` file. Then try citing something in your document. As it stands, your document has no references, so there is nothing to print.

Comment: I have used \cite{1} to refer the paper, but its giving an error  'Paragraph ended before \org@@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par                                                                                                                    \section{Introduction}
i modified the text as                                                                              It binds to DNA \cite{1} sequence.

Comment: Please check you code compiles before uploading unless the problem you want help with is that you can't get it to compile, of course. (Then you should check it produces the error you are asking about.)

Answer (score 1):

Your preamble is, frankly, a mess. I strongly suspect that you do not actually know why you are loading at least half of the packages included in your MWE (where they aren't relevant anyway). This matters because errors, mysterious weirdness and other dim and dismal happenings tend to occur when this is the case.

You do not mention compilation errors, which is very strange because, even with the obvious corrections, I could not compile your code without error. So I am not sure if this will be helpful because I'm not sure I've reproduced the problem you are having. Even if not, though, you should surely clean up the preamble.

Here are some general guidelines:

- load as many packages as you need ***and no more***;
- if uncertain whether you need a package, comment out the loading and test;
- never load a package twice;
- do not load packages which are loaded by other packages, at least when this relationship is the raison d'être for the first package's existence e.g. `amstext` is distinct from `amsmath` precisely because you might want to use the former without the latter - it serves no purpose when loading the latter (similarly for `amsfonts` and `amssymb`);
- don't load packages which are part of the package (in the CTAN sense) which provides your document class if that class loads those packages (`natmove`);
- ***never*** load packages if the documentation for your class tells you that it *modifies* the behaviour of those packages (`natbib`);
- don't load packages which try to do the same thing or to control precisely the same aspect of your document unless you are confident they are compatible - if weirdness occurs, place these packages high on your list of suspects (`achemso.cls`, `cite.sty`, `natmove.sty`, `natbib.sty` etc.).

***Read the console output.*** Warnings and errors are designed to provide you with information about what is wrong. They don't always do this very well, but sometimes they do. For example, an error told me not to use `\bibliographystyle{}` in the document. No particular knowledge of TeX or LaTeX was required to interpret that message. Errors also suggested the problems with `natmove.sty` and `cite.sty`, but those required a little more experience to interpret. But the documentation (`texdoc natmove`) told me quite a lot in very simple terms: that `achemso` modifies `natbib`, for example, and that it may require adjusting your `.bib` file for best results. I recommend it.

I've commented my modifications to your MWE below. The result produces

[image: bibliography]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{hagman1995,
  title={Resistance of Neisseria gonorrhoeae to antimicrobial hydrophobic agents is modulated by the mtrRCDE efflux system},
  author={Hagman, Kayla E and Pan, Wubin and Spratt, Brian G and Balthazar, Jacqueline T and Judd, Ralph C and Shafer, William M},
  journal={Microbiology},
  volume={141},
  number={3},
  pages={611--622},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Microbiology Society}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[journal=jacsat, layout=singlecolumn]{achemso}% loads natbib, natmove
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle=true}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}% are you really using latin1 input encoding? why? consider switching to utf8.... - not relevant for MWE
\usepackage[english]{babel}% better to specify the variant e.g. british - not relevant for MWE - also there's a weird interaction such that \cite cannot be the first thing in the document if this is loaded (but it is fine otherwise)
% \usepackage{xkeyval}% why are you loading this in a document?
% don't load cite - use achemso's facilities
\usepackage{csvsimple}% not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{amsmath}% includes amstext - not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{amssymb}% includes amsfonts - not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{graphicx}% not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{refstyle}% not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{gensymb}% not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{upgreek}% not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{array}% not relevant for MWE
\usepackage{hyperref}% should be loaded LATE - only packages which you know require later loading should be loaded later - not relevant for MWE

\title{title}% required for MWE
\begin{document}

  Some content\cite{hagman1995}% don't use bibkeys such as '1' but something meaningful; 'Some content' added for compatibility with use of babel (see above)

% don't specify another bibstyle command - the class already does this
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is always nice when down-voters leave constructive comments.